# JQuery - Paste event, stripping rich text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a contentEditable field where I'd like to do the following.  When a user pastse rich text into the field (microsoft word, or otherwise) I'd like to strip all the rich text, but retain the line breaks.

My thinking was:  If you paste rich text into a plain `<texarea>`, it removes all the formatting and retains the breaks (created by explicit new lines, as well as block level elements).  I'd like to somehow simulate this.  In other words, create a temporary textarea, intercept the paste event, apply it to the Textarea, retrieve the results, and insert them back into the original Content Editable field.

However, i haven't found a way to simulate this.  If I paste the contents into a textarea via jquery, it seems to retan all the rich text formatting when I try and copy it from there, back to the original fields

Comment: because the client will be pasting text from microsoft word, and other editors

Comment: a little confused as to why this was down-voted.  I explained what I was looking to do, what I tried, and why it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could achieve something like this without needing a `textarea`, just processing the code in the content editable `div` every time that there is a change in its value, and removing all the tags but the paragraphs and line breaks.

The idea would be that every time that the content changes in the div (listen to the `input` event):

- Replace in the inner HTML all `</p>` and `<br>` for non-HTML tokens (e.g.: `[p]` and `[br]` respectively).
- Remove all HTML tags (you can do it with `.text()`)
- Replace the tokens that you used for their equivalents (and their openings!)
- Wrap everything between `<p>` and `</p>`.

Here a simple demo:

```js
$("#editable").on("input", function() {

  $this = $(this);

  // replace all br and closing p tags with special tokens
  $this.html($this.html().replace(/\<\/p\>/g,"[p]").replace(/\<br\>/g,"[br]"));

  // remove all the tags, and then replace the tokens for their original values
  $this.html("<p>" + $this.text().replace(/\[p\]/g, "</p><p>").replace(/\[br\]/g,"<br>") + "</p>");

});
```

```css
div#editable, div#demo {
    border:1px solid gray;
    padding:6px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div contenteditable="true" id="editable"></div>

<h3>Demo</h3>
<p>Copy this code and paste it on the editable div above:</p>
<div id="demo">
  <p>This <b>is</b> <i>a</i> styled paragraph.</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>The <span style="font-weight:bold">above paragraph</span> is empty.</p>
  <p>And this is a new paragraph…<br>with a line break!</p>
</div>
```

You can also see it running on this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v5rae96w/

I tried this solution with MS Word and HTML and it works fine. But it has one issue: it only does line breaks with `p` and `br` (that works nicely with MS Word and other word processors). If the user copies HTML like `div` (or other block elements that cause a line break), it won't work as nicely. If you need to break with all block elements, this solution may require some changes.

---

To fix that, you could replace all the block tags with `p` (or `div` or the element that you want), by indicating it on the regular expression:

```
$this.html().replace(/(\<\/p\>|\<\/h1\>|\<\/h2\>|\<\/div\>)/gi,"[p]")
```

As you can see here:

```js
$("#editable").on("input", function() {
    
    $this = $(this);

    // replace all closing block tags with special token
    $this.html($this.html().replace(/(\<\/p\>|\<\/h1\>|\<\/h2\>|\<\/h3\>|\<\/h4\>|\<\/h5\>|\<\/h6\>|\<\/div\>)/gi,"[p]").replace(/\<br\>/gi,"[br]"));
    
    // remove all the tags
    $this.html("<p>" + $this.text().replace(/\[p\]/g,"</div><p>").replace(/\[br\]/g,"<br>") + "</p>");

});
```

```css
div#editable, div#demo {
    border:1px solid gray;
    padding:6px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div contenteditable="true" id="editable"></div>

<div>
    <h3>Demo</h3>
    <p>Copy this code and paste it on the editable div above:</p>
    <div id="demo">
        <p>This <b>is</b> <i>a</i> styled paragraph.</p>
        <p> </p>
        <p>The <span style="font-weight:bold">above paragraph</span> is empty.</p>
        <p>And this is a new paragraph…<br>with a line break!</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Or on this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v5rae96w/1/

Comment: The above solution has a bug, if you try to type it causes issues. Try typing "ok" it shows as "ko"